# How do you manage naming clashes generated when importing different namespaces in ruby?

Tags: ruby

Lets' say I have 2 modules:

```
# a/foo.rb
module A
   class Foo
   end
end
```

and

```
# b/foo.rb
module B
   class Foo
   end
end
```

As you can see they both expose a `Foo` class. Now, in my main file I do:

```
load "./a/foo.rb"
load "./b/foo.rb"

include A
include B

i = Foo.new() // this is probably B::Foo isn't it?
```

How can I differentiate the 2 `Foo` classes? Is there any aliasing facility in the language that help me preventing the overlapping between the two `Foo`s?

Thanks

Comment: Instead of `load "./a/foo.rb"`, you should probably use `require_relative "a/foo"`.

Answer (score 3):

> this is probably `B::Foo` isn't it?

Yes, it is.

Just use the namespace resolution operator (`::`) to refer the right constant:

- `A::Foo.new` #=> `A::Foo:0x007fb9e5b8caa8`
- `B::Foo.new` #=> `B::Foo:0x007fb9e5b549f0`

Comment: Furthermore, it's probably a bad idea to include both modules in the first place if there is a name conflict.